# Wrong Wolfram Alpha result for $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^4}{x^4+x^2+y^4}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, wolfram-alpha

> I'm trying to solve this limit:
>   $$
> \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^4}{x^4+x^2+y^4}
> $$

---

Here's my attempt:

$$0 \le |\frac{xy^4}{x^4+x^2+y^4} - 0| = \frac{|x|y^4}{x^4+x^2+y^4},$$ and since $x^4+x^2 \ge0$ then $\frac{y^4}{x^4+x^2+y^4} \le 1$ so 
$$
\frac{|x|y^4}{x^4+x^2+y^4} \le |x|,$$ so 
$$
0 \le \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|\frac{xy^4}{x^4+x^2+y^4} - 0| \le \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} |x| = 0,
$$ and using the squeeze theorem the limit is $0$.

But if I input the limit in wolfram alpha, it says that the limit doesn't exist. Here is the [link to the limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B(x*y%5E4)%2F(x%5E4%2By%5E4%2Bx%5E2),+%7Bx+-%3E+0,+y+-%3E+0%7D%5D) in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Even for your initially question that $y^{2}$ in below, it still gets the limit zero, which I have shown in the new answer, which is essentially the same thought that you proved. Sorry for the first answer that I messed up.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21562/664) answer from Mathematica.stackexchange, which would give the correct answer for your particular limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of

$$\frac{xy^{4}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+y^{4}},\,\,\frac{xy^{4}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

have limit $0.$ For the first one, you gave a valid proof. The second one follows from this one since the denominator is at least as big, while the numerator is the same.

Comment: But for the second one, if we put $x=y^{2}$, it seems giving us trouble, did I compute something wrong?

Comment: You made a mistake there. Check again.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

For 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{xy^{4}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+y^{2}},
\end{align*}
one does the following step which is similar to your technique:
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{xy^{4}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\leq|xy^{2}|\cdot\dfrac{y^{2}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+y^{2}}\leq|x|\cdot y^{2}\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use polar coordinate by letting $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ and the limit becomes $$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^5 \cos \theta \sin^4\theta}{r^4\cos^4\theta + r^2\cos^2\theta + r^4\sin^4\theta} = \lim_{r\to 0} r^3\left(\frac{\cos\theta\sin^4\theta}{r^2\cos^4\theta+\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^4\theta}\right) = 0$$

Today's lesson is : Don't trust Wolframalpha entirely

Comment: How do you know that the denominator $r^2\cos^4\theta+\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^4\theta$ is away from $0$?

Comment: If $\cos \theta \neq 0$ the denominator will not be $0$, and if $\cos \theta = 0$ the denominator  will be $r^2$ which you can cancel with $r^3$ leaving $r$.

Comment: When $\cos\theta=0$, the whole fraction in the parentheses is zero. I see your point.